# Pilot light device with

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to upgrade the light switches in a room.  I have a 3 gang box, two single pole switches and an indicator light for one of them (the basement light switch). The indicator light is its own thing and uses its own space in the box. All I find in the big box stores is switches with built in indicators. But I need to fill three slots in the box. And I would also need the switch cover to have a lens to show when the indicator is on.  Can't find that either. What's currently installed is from the 1960s and needs to be replaced. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you checked with a local electrical supply house?  Product recs don't fit the Stack model due to market turnover, but the folks behind the counter at your local supply house should be able to find you what you're after

Comment: Kyle’s switch plate carries that: https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/switch-plate-caps-jewels-lights/

Comment: Google "aliexpress pilot light 110v" for a raft of rpund pilot lights you can drill a hole for and clip in

Comment: @davidgo ***No, don't.*** AliExpress aka Alibaba is not legal (NEC 110.2) to use in mains electrical, being a sea of cheap Cheese junk that has never seen the inside of a reputable testing lab. If you want to use it on low voltage electronics experimentation, have fun; but for mains it's right out.

Comment: The right place to source electrical parts is an electrical supply house that is willing to give you trade prices; many will if you don't obviously need a ton of handholding.  The secret password is "Home Depot's prices are worse than their selection".

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question right what you are looking for is a jewel light, which you won't find in a big box retail store but you should be able to find on line. This is an image of a red jewel light.

[image]

If that seems a little more than you want to handle, you might try and install a switch with a lighted handle and buy a wall switch blank for the other slot.

[image]

These can be found in some big box hardware stores, usually in white. If not then you can also order these on line.

Good luck.

Comment: Perfect! A jewel light. I didn't know what they were called. Either the jewel light or blank and lighted switch will do the job. Thank you very much.